# What is the probability of losing $5$ bets in a row when the chance to win increases after each loss.

Tags: probability

> 1) I play a bet with $32\%$ chance of winning it;
>   2) If I lose that, I then play a bet with $64\%$ chance of winning it;
>   3) If I lose that, I then play a bet with $81\%$ chance of winning it;
>   4) If I lose that, I then play a bet with $89\%$ chance of winning it;
>   5) If I lose that, I then play a bet with $94\%$ chance of winning it;
>   What is the probability of losing all $5$ bets in a row?

What type of probability is used to calculate this and similar situations like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use simple constructive probability. Instead of looking at the winning probabilities, look at the losing probabilities, which in this case are the "successful" outcomes. Solve for the probability as follows.
$$(1 - 0.32)(1 - 0.64)(1 - 0.81)(1 - 0.89)(1 - 0.94).$$

This is about $\boxed{0.031\%}.$